# Provide size argument to List<T>()

Tags: c#, performance, list

The default capacity of `List<T>()` in `System.Collections.Generic` is 0.

Say I have a function

```
private IEnumerable<SomeType> DoStuff(IEnumerable<OtherType> e)
{
    var list = new List<SomeType>();
    foreach (var elem in e)
    {
        list.Add(new SomeType
        {
            SomeProperty = elem.OtherProperty
        });
    }
    return list;
}
```

and I set the size of `list` before running the loop like so:

```
private IEnumerable<SomeType> DoStuff(IEnumerable<OtherType> e)
{
    var list = new List<SomeType>(e.Count());
    foreach (var elem in e)
    {
        list.Add(new SomeType
        {
            SomeProperty = elem.OtherProperty
        });
    }
    return list;
}
```

does it make a difference in running time or is there no reason to do this because the size of `e` is 'dynamic'?

Comment: Try it and see. Providing a size large enough for the expected contents will prevent the reallocations that take place under the hood.

Comment: But if youre just performing a transformation on one list, why aren't you just using LINQ's Select() ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the type of `IEnumerable<OtherType> e`...

```
e.Count()
```

could enumerate the `e` just to count it... if `e` was a query against the db, it would be executed twice, once for the `e.Count()` and once for the `foreach`... slow!

If `e` is a `List<>` or a `OtherType[]` or other types that implement `ICollection<>` then the `Count()` uses the `Count` property, so it doesn't enumerate the `IEnumerable<>`.

Note that for this simple case you could:

```
return e.Select(x => new SomeType { SomeProperty = x.OtherProperty })
        .ToList();
```

Now... as @Jonathan noticed, you are returning a `IEnumerable<>`, so you could:

```
return e.Select(x => new SomeType { SomeProperty = x.OtherProperty });
```

and live happy... or you could

```
private IEnumerable<SomeType> DoStuff(IEnumerable<OtherType> e)
{
    foreach (var elem in e)
    {
        yield return new SomeType
        {
            SomeProperty = elem.OtherProperty
        };
    }
}
```

(that would be nearly equivalent to doing the `Select`, but if you have a complex expression for transforming the elements, perhaps using the `Select` becomes burdensome)

Or, if you really want to create a `List<>` and presize it if it is possible:

```
ICollection<T> c = e as ICollection<T>;
int count = c != null ? c.Count : 0;

var list = new List<SomeType>(count);
```

As always, remember that you **shouldn't** enumerate an `IEnumerable<>` more than once, unless you are **really really** sure that

1. It is really a `List<>` or other collection in disguise, so that the data already exists, and there are no problems enumerating it multiple times

or

2. You know that each time the `IEnumerable<>` is enumerated it will be rebuilt from scratch, but the cost is negligible.

Comment: `Select` is the way to go for 1 to 1 list.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Because he was building a `List<>` There could be some timing difference in "caching" the `IEnumerable<>` :-) Yes... you can remove the `ToList<>()` if you want

Comment: Fair enough. If you're going to use this result just once, drop the ToList() and let it be lazily evaluated. If it's going to be used often, the ToList() will accomplish what the OP has in the most efficient way possible (because the size is known).

Answer (score 3):

**Don't do this.** This way, you're enumerating the sequence `e` twice: once within `foreach`, once through `Count()`.

The idea behind giving the capacity to the `List<T>` constructor is to prevent unnecessary array allocations. The list grows dynamically, meaning it allocates a new array that is twice as long when necessary. If it knows the required capacity upfront, `List<T>` can allocate an array of the correct size right from the start.

General advice regarding *does it make a difference in running time*: **measure, don't assume**. You might save on array allocations here, but you'll probably be slower because you iterate over the sequence more than once.

Comment: *Maybe*. .Count() can be specialized for things like arrays and run in O(1) because the size is known.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But since `DoStuff` accepts any sequence, you shouldn't iterate more than once. You could attempt a cast, though, and base your decision on that.